# For a compact set K, does $K\supset f(K)\supset f^{2}(K)\supset...$ hold for function f?

Tags: real-analysis

Let $K$ be a compact normed space  and $f:K\rightarrow K$ such that $$\|f(x)-f(y)\|<\|x-y\|\quad\quad\forall\,\, x, y\in K, x\neq y.$$

Is it true that $K\supset f(K)\supset f^{2}(K)\supset...$?
How to show it?

Comment: Normed spaces tend not to be compact...

Comment: The question in your title and in the body of your post are different.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez Depends on whether "$f:X\to Y$" means $Y$ is the codomain or $Y$ is the range, doesn't it? For example $f:[0,1]\to [0,1]$  taking $f(x) = 0$ does not have $[0,1]\subseteq f([0,1])$.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez thanks for pointing it out. Updated the notation. Maybe i need to go out and take a rest. been stuck on this exercise for too long.

Comment: "$f:X\to Y$ means that $Y$ is the codomain, @Neal.

Comment: If you reverse the inclusions, as you jut did,then the result is obvious. f(K) has to be contained in $K$ because the codomain of $f$ is $K$.

Comment: Probably what you mean is that $K$ is a compact subset of a normed space so that $K$ is equipped with a metric induced from the norm of the ambient space. Also, notice that (1) $f(K) \subseteq K$ is trivial because $K$ is the codomain of $f$, and (2) if $A \subseteq B \subseteq K$ then $f(A) \subseteq f(B)$. Now you may use (1) and (2) recursively to show $K \supseteq f(K) \subseteq f^2(K) \supseteq \cdots $.

Comment: Maybe you re missing the fact that if $A\subseteq B$ then $f(A)\subseteq f(B)$.

Comment: I do not believe f need to be onto. I think f sort of works like a contraction. Why is your second point i.e if A⊆B then f(A)⊆f(B) true?

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez why is this the case? if A⊆B then f(A)⊆f(B)

Comment: If $x$ is in $f(A)$, then there exists an $a$ in $A$ such that $x=f(a)$. Now, since $A\subseteq B$, the element $a$ is also in $B$, and then $x=f(a)\in f(B)$.

Answer (score 4):

If this were true, then all points of the space would be fixed: every set of the form $\{x\}$ is compact.

(and then the map would be the identity, which is impossible...)

Answer (score 2):

This is not true.  Take $f(x) = x^2$ on $[0,\frac{1}{2}]$.  Then $K = [0,\frac{1}{2}]$, and $f(K) = [0,\frac{1}{4}]$.

Comment: f(x)=$x^2$ does not satisfy ∥f(x)−f(y)∥<∥x−y∥∀x,y∈K,x≠y.

Comment: Yeah it does...

Comment: An exercise for you : Suppose that $f$ is a real valued differentiable function on an interval $I$.  If $f'$ is bounded on $I$, then $f$ is Lipschitz on $I$.

Comment: Oh ok you need the constant to be $1$.  Fine.  Take $f(x) = \frac{1}{2}x^2$ instead.